# Get shipping label using Paypal API

Tags: paypal

How to get shipping label using Paypal API?

I have seen several examples where sending form on http://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ship-now and parse the results, but did not find how to send the parcel using Paypal API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Perl/LWP to simulate a browser to put in the user address and package information to generate the shipping label. And then we download the image files into our local file system. 
After that, we format the image file to fit our printers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PayPal does not have API's for shipping labels or tracking numbers.  I've been begging for it for years.